# Which package is pango that is needed to compile Qemu with --enable-gtk enabled?

Tags: package-management, compiling, qemu, gtk3, pango

I'm compiling Qemu with `--enable-gtk` enabled. `.configure` gives me the following error messages:

```
Run-time dependency gtk+-3.0 found: NO

../meson.build:1042:2: ERROR: Could not generate cargs for gtk+-3.0:
Package pango was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pango.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'pango', required by 'gdk-3.0'(is this a typo?), not found


A full log can be found at .../qemu-6.2.0-rc2/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt

ERROR: meson setup failed
```

I searched in [Ubuntu package search webpage](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search) for 'pango', but it gives me so many results that I don't know which one is the correct 'pango' I should install to pass the `gtk-3` configure. So, what is the package name for 'pango' that `gtk+-3.0` needs?

PS, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and the Qemu I'm trying to build is 6.2.

Comment: All packages required for building source code with e.g. meson must be (lib)name-dev → Example →  `sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pango&searchon=names

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools involved into building process. One of them is `pkg-config`. It searches for files with `.pc` extension. For Gtk3
and Pango you need to install [the following](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gtk%2B-3.0.pc) [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=pango.pc&searchon=contents):

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libpango1.0-dev
```

But finding and installing every single package may be time consuming procedure. So you have two options here:

- install build-dependencies for existing QEMU by

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get build-dep qemu
  ```

  and then compile newer QEMU on your own.
- install newer binary QEMU 6.0 from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eflexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/quickemu?field.series_filter=focal) using commands below:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/quickemu
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install qemu
  ```

Comment: None of them works for me.