# Availability of liburing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, compiling, qemu

I am building qemu with `--enable-linux-io-uring` option on Ubuntu 20.04, which requires `liburing`. But if I tried to install packages `liburing1` and `liburing-dev` using apt, I was told "E: Unable to locate package liburing-dev or liburing1". I checked Ubuntu package official website, these packages are really not shown under focal distribution. So I wanna 1) confirm that packages `liburing1` and `liburing-dev` are not available in Ubuntu 20.04, 2) if so, how to build qemu with `linux-io-uring` feature on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: These packages are available for [newer releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=liburing&searchon=names). You are compiling QEMU for [four days](https://askubuntu.com/a/1378256/66509). Are you really sure that you need to go this way? Maybe it is time to [use PPA](https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/quickemu?field.series_filter=focal)? It has both QEMU and liburing.

Comment: @N0rbert: What choice do I have? I asked but no one answers or even downvote or close my question. You answer but your answer just doesn't work. Let me tell you again, your PPA answer just don't work!

Comment: How exactly "PPA answer just don't work"? Please add relevant error messages to the above question or upload to pastebin. It is hard to help when have 1% percent of information, and other 99% are hidden in your mind and logs.

Comment: @N0rbert: For "sudo apt-get build-dep qemu". The error is "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.". I have completely rebuilt a new sources.list but got the same error. For PPA, I checked that guy's website, it has only "quickemu", no "qemu-system-x86_64". Also, I'm not a super user, so no way to execute any sudo command.

Comment: You have to get `sudo` access first. Please run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, followed by `sudo apt-get install -f` with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and share full error output of above commands.

Comment: @N0rbert: I'm not a super user of the machine I really want to build qemu. I can contact sys admin but usually he will respond after a week (when he will likely leave for Xmas holiday). I'm trying to figure out how to use the PPA without root privilege. I'm also building qemu on a ubuntu where I am a root, on which, however, "sudo apt-get build-dep qemu" doesn't work. If your last comment is about this, the three command gave no error, but I still received "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." This is the /etc/apt/sources.list file: https://pastebin.com/0dxLTVyr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it, and here I record it as an answer for the non-conformist whose work has creative and cracking nature.

I downloaded `liburing1` and `liburing-dev` package deb files `liburing1_0.6-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb` and `liburing-dev_0.6-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb` from another ubuntu variant. Then I use `sudo dpkg -x <def file name> /` to install liburing. After that, `./configure`, `make & make install` of qemu succeeds and generated the needed qemu-system-x86_64.

I have not seen any problem so far.